# How to sniff csv line separators/terminators (csv.Sniffer() not working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following data, which uses `\x01` as the field separator and `\x02\n` as the line separator. Here is an example of the data:

```
#export_date\x01artist_id\x01name\x01is_actual_artist\x01view_url\x01artist_type_id\x02\n#primaryKey:artist_id\x02\n
#dbTypes:BIGINT\x01INTEGER\x01VARCHAR(1000)\x01BOOLEAN\x01VARCHAR(1000)\x01INTEGER\x02\n#exportMode:INCREMENTAL\x02\n
1475226000146\x011120695691\x01Kinitic SA\x011\x01http://itunes.apple.com/artist/kinitic-sa/id1120695691?uo=5\x017\x02\n
```

However, here is what I get when I try parsing this with the `csv` module:

```
with open('myfile', 'r') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    print(dialect.__dict__)
```

> mappingproxy({'**module**': 'csv', '_name': 'sniffed', 'lineterminator': '\r\n', 'quoting': 0, '**doc**': None, 'doublequote': False, 'delimiter': ' ', 'quotechar': '"', 'skipinitialspace': False})

Unfortunately, this is wrong, as it thinks the delimiter is a space (even if I increase the buffer size it's wrong).

Is there a more accurate way to determine the separator and lineterminator than using that module?

Comment: Sniffer heuristics probably don't extend to those weird separators. Checking source code, default is  `self.preferred = [',', '\t', ';', ' ', ':']`

Comment: `sniff` takes an optional `delimiters` parameter, a string containing all possible delimiters. Have you tried that, would it be feasible to use in your case?

Comment: if you know what the separators are, why are you sniffing the file?

Comment: @cody -- I suppose. Is there something like a list of all possible delimiters? Unfortunately, I'm using this for lots of delimiters and I'm not sure what are actual legitimate delimiters and what aren't.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- I don't: I'm just using this as an example (from one that I do not to see if it's actually working).

Comment: @David542 Unfortunately, a delimiter could really be any character. That's why I was wondering if in your use case, there was a finite list of possibilities.

Comment: csv module tries to see which character "predominates" in a list of given characters. There's also a detection based on identical characters (quotes) followed by a separator.

Comment: with your data, `\x01` appears 15 times, but `t` appears 20 times. How can we know which separator it is without more information? you _need_ more information on the separator and line terminator, otherwise it's not answerable

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you want me to provide more data in the question?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- also, `t` could appear a lot -- for example for any url fields, etc.

Comment: in your example, a human would understand what the separator is, because it's radically different from other letters, but consider: `abaacabaacabaacabc` which one of `b` or `c` is the separator? if we rule out letters and digits, that will be easier.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it seems like the Sniffer is pretty terrible with inferring non-standard characters. Using `SEPARATORS = ['\x01']` worked, but doing `SEPARATORS = ['\x01', ':']` chose the wrong one, the `:`.

Comment: rather than reading 1024 bytes, try passing in a line. I've found that giving the sniffer too much data often causes it to guess incorrectly

Comment: @badger -- could you please give an example of how that would be done? I know it might sound silly, but how do you know what a line is? Do you do file.readlines()[0] ? What if, for example, there is a `\n` in the text of the first line of data (I haven't seen this on the first line, but a `\n` is often in the text itself.

Comment: @badger0053 -- does my example below in my answer seem valid?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hackish, but you could count the number of characters in an input stream for those possible separators. For example:

```
import collections

SEPARATORS=['\x00', '\x01', '\x02\n', '^', ':', ',', '\t', ':', ';', '|', '~']

def count_separator(filename, separators=SEPARATORS):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read(1024*1024)
    counts = collections.Counter(c for c in text if c in SEPARATORS)
    print (counts)
    return c.most_common()[0][0]

>>> count_separator('/Users/david/Desktop/validate_headers/artist')
Counter({'\x01': 48549, ':': 9752, '\x02': 9741, ',': 295, ';': 3})
'\x01'
```

Another option, suggested by badger0053 above, is to only use the first line of data for the sniffer. This seems to work much better:

```
SEPARATORS=['\x00', '\x01',  '^', ':', ',', '\t', ':', ';', '|', '~', ' ']
LINE_TERMINATORS_IN_ORDER = ['\x02\n', '\r\n', '\n', '\r']
with open('/Users/david/Desktop/validate_headers/artist', 'r') as csvfile:
    line = next(csvfile)
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(line, SEPARATORS)
    for _terminator in LINE_TERMINATORS_IN_ORDER:
        if line.endswith(_terminator):
            terminator = _terminator
            break
    print(repr(dialect.delimiter), repr(terminator))
```

> '\x01' '\x02\n'

Comment: @gboffi -- thanks, how is that superior to what I'm doing? I'm sure it is, I'm just curious as I (obviously) haven't used that much before.